# How can I check if a vector with a custom class is NULL?

Tags: c++, class, if-statement, vector, null

I have made this custom class

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H_
#define VEHICLE_H_

Class Vehicle {
 public:
 Vehicle();
 Vehicle(char,char,int,int);
 virtual ~Vehicle();
 char getLicense_plate();
 void setLicense_plate(char);
 char getBrand();
 void setBrand(char);
 int getTime_in();
 void setTime_in(int);
 int getTime_out();
 void setTime_out(int);

 char license_plate;
 char brand;
 int timei;
 int timeo;
};
```

And I have created a Vehicle vector with size 50 in the main.cpp but I don't how  to check each value if they are empty.

```
#inlcude<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#inlude "Vehicle.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<Vehicle> avai_space(50);
for(int i=0;i<avai_space.size();i++)
 { 
  //if(avai_space(i) == NULL??){}
```

Comment: They're not "empty" - the vector contains 50 `Vehicle`s, all constructed by the default constructor. (C++ isn't Java.)

Comment: They can't be null, they are not pointers. You have 50 default constructed Vehicles in this vector.

Comment: Why do you have class capitalized?

Comment: `char license_plate;` `char brand;` 1 character to store a license plate or brand? Use std::string instead of char for these and the the getters and setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector<Vehicle> avai_space(50);` does not create an empty vector with a storage capacity of 50; it creates a vector with 50 valid entries where each entry gets initialized using the default constructor of `Vehicle` class.

To create an empty vector with max storage of 50, use:

```
vector<Vehicle> vehicle_vec;
vehicle_vec.reserve(50);
```

You can use `vehicle_vec.push_back()` to add items into the vector without affecting the storage.

Once the vector is populated with entries, you can now use `vehicle_vec.size()` to iterate through the valid entries in this vector:

```
for (size_t i = 0 ; i < vehicle_vec.size() ; i++) {
    // Use vehicle_vec[i], for e.g.
    std::cout << vehicle_vec[i].brand << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok i got the point but after creating the vector i used
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<vehicle.vec.size();i++)
    {
    if(vehicle.vec[i].size()== NULL)
    {}
to find out which spots are empty but it results in an error!

Comment: Vehicle does not contain a size() member and if it did comparing size to NULL does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @user4433128 You cannot check if a particular element in the vector is valid or not. What you can do is to see how many elements are valid and iterate only among the valid ones

Answer (score 1):

None of the elements will ever be 'empty', as in a null pointer, because they're stored by value, not by pointer.

That scenario would correspond to a declaration like

```
std::vector<Vehicle*>
```

or, if the pointers need to own the objects

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Vehicle>>
```

Comment: `boost::optional` would be better. There is no need for dynamic allocation here; you're increasing your allocation overhead by an order of magnitude and caning memory locality, both for no reason at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That's a good point. I was just following the OP's pointer-oriented line of reasoning and trying to clarify why there are no nulls in his example.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<Vehicle> avai_space(50);` creates 50 `Vehicles`. They exist after this line and are not empty, but what ever `Vehicle`'s default constructor makes them.

If you want to store `Vehicles` in your vector, but not create them yet (I assume that's what you mean with `== NULL`), just write `vector<Vehicle> avai_space;` and then add new `Vehicles`s to the end with [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back).